# Double @synchronized: is it needed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

My app is a port from an Android application and I have these two methods:

```
- (MyObject*)getMyObject:(MyObjectType)myObjectType
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < [myObjects count]; index++)
        {
            MyObject* myObject = (MyObject*)[myObjects objectAtIndex:index];
            if (myObject.Type == myObjectType)
                return myObject;
        }

        return nil;
    }
}

- (BOOL)isMyObjectVisible:(MyObjectType)myObjectType
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        return ([self getMyObject:myObjectType] != nil);
    }
}
```

I have `isMyObjectVisible:`, that is `@synchronized`, calling another `@synchronized` method.

**Is it necessary that `isMyObjectVisible:` has to be `@synchronized`?**

Comment: You are probably doing this **Just to be sure of thread safety**. Kindly read [@synchronized and threadSafety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392726/does-synchronized-guarantees-for-thread-safe-or-not)

Comment: Have you tried it?  It looks like an immediate deadlock to me...

Comment: @borrrden, the lock in this case is a *recursive* one, so it won't deadlock the program.  It's just unnecessary, and slightly wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, **no**, the double locking is not needed.

You can keep the lock in `getMyObject`.  That protects it.  However, there is nothing in `isMyObjectVisible` other than a call to `getMyObject`, so there's nothing **else** to protect in that method.

However, borrrden's comment is not an issue here.  You get a [recursive lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex) when [using @synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956919/119114), so you can nest `synchronized` calls like you're doing without a deadlock.  There's just no **need** to, in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Example of that  you need to use  double @synchronized :

```
NSString * str;
str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"str"];

-(void)viewDidLoad{

  NSString *foo = @"foo";
  NSString *bar = @"bar";
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  [self firstAction:foo];
  });
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  [self secondAction:bar];
  });
}
- (void)firstAction:(NSString *)sender {
    NSLog(@"firstAction");
    @synchronized (self) {
        str = sender;
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            NSLog(@"first: %@",str);
        }
    }
}

- (void)secondAction:(NSString *)sender {
        NSLog(@"secondAction");
        @synchronized (self) {
            str = sender;
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                NSLog(@"second: %@",str);
            }
        }  
 }
```

(str is static variable )
-Try to run it without the @synchronized (self)  and see what will happen.